# Copy rows from one sheet to form entries sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

This function copies the 3 rows currently in sheet ss3 to sheet ss, so far so good. But sheet ss is also used for input from a form. As soon as entries are made in the form they are saved in sheet ss and the 3 rows copied from ss3 disapears.

How do I get the form entry to be saved at the first empty row, number 6 in this case, and leave the copied rows in place?

```
function fasta() {
// Copy from 2nd row, all rows for one column 
var valuesToCopy = ss3.getRange(2, 1, ss3.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
//Paste to another sheet, row 3 column 9
ss.getRange(3,9,valuesToCopy.length,1).setValues(valuesToCopy);
}
```

Comment: Best solution is not to mess with form linked sheets.

Comment: Leave the form responses sheet alone and create a new sheet for merging your data.

Comment: Solved by copying to another sheet